# peer js Audio chat

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I am just looking on a chat application which is given in the https://github.com/nwah/peerjs-audio-chat

Actually its quite intresting to chat with just two browsers. I have some doubts regarding this peer js. I got also my free Api key from there website

I just started the application with the instructions given in the github link.

```
1. But What should i do, if i want to get Connected with another user with another API key.

2. Suppose There is someone in another computer, with another Api key, Will he'll be connected, Is there any specification if he want to run the app in same port number as given in for my app
```

Because I am not getting connected i tried many ways, Always getting error for the connection, Is there any thing else that Other user should do, if he want to connect with me...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me. One chat app will be normally using one API key. So, all connecting users will have the same API key. Please correct me if I got the question wrong.

( Don't have enough reputation or would have left this as a comment. )

Answer (score 0):

Two peers are connected using provided unique peerId of the other side of the call. The API key that you signed up for is just a way to connect your peers using intermediary server for the initial connection (There's an option to host your own server that will handle establishing connections).

1. You can't.
2. No.

I believe your problems fundamentally come from misunderstanding some networking concepts.